# Why is the UV absorption band for molecules not a sudden transition?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vibrations

From what I have read, when a molecule in solution or gas is excited, it does so from ground state, but may gain the energy for vibrational transitions as well. This would lead me to expect that there would be a sudden change in absorption with a long band of absorption (with some variation there in). However, what I find is that the transition is not sudden, but sloped. I am particularly interested in the slope of nitrate in water. Why is this? Are there molecule-molecule interactions? Are the molecules starting at an excited state?

Comment: Have you got a specific example (i.e. a specific reference) in mind?

Comment: UV absorption of nitrate in water is a good example. The peak is at 210nm, but it has a slope extending to 245nm.

Answer (score 0):

When a photon interacts with an atom (or molecule in this case) three things can happen:

1. elastic scattering, when the photon keeps its energy and phase, and changes angle
2. inelastic scattering, when the photon gives part of its energy to the atomic or molecular system, and changes angle
3. absorption, when the photon gives all of its energy to the atomic or molecular system

In the case of photo electricity, or at higher energies, it is number 3 that happens, but number 2 can happen too.

Now 1. usually happens on the surface (like in the case of a mirror).

In your case, for UV, at higher energies, that happens deeper inside the material. In this case, usually 2. and 3. can happen, and some molecules get excited.

In this case, the photon's energy gets partially (2.) or fully (3.) transformed into the vibrational energies of the molecules.

Now you are asking, why not all molecules get excited at the same level, that is, all of them would need to move from their ground state to the same excited energy level. That is what you call a sudden transition. But instead, you find a sloped transition.

The reason for that is:

1. some photons transfer their energy only partially (inelastic scattering), some fully (absorption) to the molecule's vibrational energy. In the case of partial excitation (inelastic scattering), the photon's energy only partially gets transformed into the molecule's vibrational energy. Now each molecule will get a different level of that partial energy. That is why all molecules will move up to a different energy level.
2. In the case of absorption, you would expect that all molecules get excited to the same energy level, considering that all photons are the same energy level. But that would mean too, that all molecules were at the same ground level, and there is no connection between the molecules' vibrational energyies (temperature) in the lattice. But in reality, the molecules have different ground levels, and as they absorb the photons' energies, the vibration energies tend to equalize through the lattice, in a way that molecules with higher energy levels will transfer part of their energy level to other molecules' vibrational energies. That is how temperature will try to equalize out through the lattice.
3. There are not only single photon absorptions, but multi (two) photon absorptions too. In this case, one single molecule can absorb more then one photon. In this case the molecule will have a different energy level too.
4. There is something called multi molecule (two) excitation, when a photon excites more then one molecule. In this case the molecules will have different energy levels too.

It is important to understand too, that you are asking whether molecules are starting at excited states. In the case of UV higher energies, we are talking about vibrational energies of the molecules, that is their temperature. Obviously, not all molecules will have the same vibrational energy levels in the lattice.

You are asking too, whether there are molecule-molecule interactions. Yes, since we are talking about vibrational energies, and temperature, these energy levels naturally try to equalize out through the lattice, that is, molecules with higher energy levels will transfer some of their energies to other neighboring molecules that have lower energy levels until they will equal out.